# What will happen with reminders after Google Inbox dies?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail, google-calendar-reminders

We have heard a couple days ago that Google is going to shut down Google Inbox in about 6 months, so that they can concentrate on GMail.

My question is: what is going to happen now with "reminders"? The migration guide says that we should use Google Tasks, but this app does not allow for recurrent reminders.

Is this feature going to disappear completely? As of today, it is possible to set reminders in Google Calendar. Are those going to be gone as well?

Comment: There is a LOT more that reminders can do that tasks can't. First, tasks don't actually remind you! The most important feature for me is being able to make each and every email into a reminder. And being integrated right inside your inbox. Can't do that with tasks. Also being able to snooze by location. Can you add a task by voice on your mobile device? Can with reminders. And you can set reminders not only in inbox and calendar but also from Google keep. I hope more of these things make it into Gmail soon. Otherwise Google is taking us back to the dark ages of personal productivity.

Comment: Reminders are integrated with calendar, keep, assistant, etc. Tasks is just a standalone app, not integrated in gmail besides being in the sidebar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019

Answer (score 2):

There's a "tasks" feature in Gmail, in my case on the right side of the page in a vertical bar. If you open it up and click the three-dot menu to the right of "add task", you're presented with the opportunity to "copy all reminders to tasks".

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another way to quickly create Reminders in Gmail: use IFTTT's "Note" widget on the Today screen of my iPhone, and then use the "snooze" feature of Gmail to remind me later about them.

Here a tutorial on how I did this: [How to add Reminders to Gmail, like in Google Inbox](https://medium.com/@adrienjoly/how-to-add-reminders-to-gmail-like-in-google-inbox-f81fb5ef9ab5)

[image: Inbox-like Reminder in Gmail for iPhone]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I found the site referred to by Boris:
https://www.inboxreminder.me/

But when I tried it to send a test reminder "Now", it didn't work.  Also, as this reddit user explained, it's also a security risk because it shares the reminders you create through the app with a 3rd party:
https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/9krgwi/reminder_in_inbox_whats_the_gmail_equivalent/?st=jseryt1y&sh=c54944ba

Even if it did work, it wouldn't be as integrated with Gmail as it used to be with Inbox.  From its description, I think it just emails you your reminder at a specific time.  That means I won't be able to see or manage my "snoozed" reminders that haven't yet come up for the first time.

I haven't tried it yet, but as I research a Gmail-integrated replacement for Google Inbox reminders, this is what looks the most promising:
https://www.fastcompany.com/90237978/heres-how-to-recreate-google-inboxs-best-features-in-gmail

Answer (score -1):

Today Google Task added the ability to set recurrent reminders!

Comment: Talk about cutting it close... -_- But this is not sync with the "reminders" in the Calendar, right?

Answer (score -3):

I recreated the InboxReminder functionality in the site https://inboxreminder.me.

It works quit easily in that you add your email, and get it installed as a widget (progressive web app) on android as an app to create reminders and receive an email in your gmail whenever the reminder is due.

Comment: The link is dead