# Can I convert past "Inbox by Gmail" reminders to anything useful?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

Inspired by [What will happen with reminders after Google Inbox dies?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120572/), which focuses mainly on future and, in particular, recurring reminders, I would like to know what happens to past ("Done") reminders, both the stand-alone ones as well as the note ones attached to emails.

And, more specifically, is there a way for me to convert "Done" reminders into something (like fake emails) that I can use (read, search, find) in Gmail? If so, could note ones be associated to the corresponding email thread?

I have checked various Gmail APIs, and none of them seem to allow me to access any "Inbox by Gmail"-specific information, which is a bummer. How do I takeout these data?

Answer (score 1):

For a personal gmail account, you can download the set of reminders (past & present) on https://takeout.google.com. I haven't yet come across a way to convert them to "fake emails" in gmail as you suggest, sadly.

Comment: Yes, this works! Unfortunately, the notes attached to email threads, after export, do not carry any information that would help me relate them to the thread there were attached to...